# Sublime - How can I wrap a text with or without regular expression?

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

```
<p>Jean was a little girl, and she liked programming very much.</p>
<p>One day, Jean went to Annie's house and saw a very surprising work Annie had done, by accident.</p>
<p>Annie then let Jean join her secret work...</p>
```

This is an example, and my article are full with names and special nouns.
So, I need to wrap all names I want with regular expression.
The result should be like:

```
<p><span class="name">Jean</span> was a little girl, and she liked <span class="special">programming</span> very much.</p>
<p>One day, <span class="name">Jean</span> went to <span class="name">Annie</span>'s house and saw a very surprising work <span class="name">Annie</span> had done, by accident.</p>
<p><span class="name">Annie</span> then let <span class="name">Jean</span> join her secret work...</p>
```

How can I wrap a text with Sublime's find-and-replace function?
It is a function like [jQuery's wrap function](https://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

Answer (score 0):

In Find, put each word, separated by vertical bars, in the centre capture group. The first and last captures groups ensure you wont put a span around a word which already has a span around it:

```
(p>|[^>])(Jeanie|Jean Smith|Jean|Annie)(</p|[^<])
```

And in Replace put:

```
$1<span class="name">$2</span>$3
```

And click Replace All.

Edit:
If any replacing-word, *a*, is a sub-string of another replacing-word, *b*, then *a* needs to come after *b* in the capture group.

E.g if a=Jean and b=Jeanie then:
(Jeanie|Jean) Will work as expected.
(Jean|Jeanie) Will not.

Comment: How about a name with space? for example, 'Jean Smith' thank you

Comment: @JeanYang As I said, just add it into the middle capture. Jean Smith has Jean as a sub-string so it will need to be before Jean. E.g: (p>|[^>])(Jeanie|Jean Smith|Jean|Annie)(</p|[^<]) Once you have an answer that is suitable don't forget to accept it using the tick underneath the down-vote arrow :)